# Inheritance and Private attributes in Python

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self._lst = []


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Considering the code above, say I wanted to implement a method in the Child class, am I allowed to used self._lst (which is a private attribute initialized in the Parent Class) for this method? In other words, am I allowed to access private attributes that are initialized in the Parent Class through Subclasses?

Comment: `self._lst` (with one underscore) would be accessible from the subclass.  `self.__lst` (with two underscores) would not.

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed"? Allowed by *whom*? The people reviewing your code? Maybe not. Did you *try*?

Comment: @jasonharper that is incorrect, those attributes are *accessible from anywhere*.  Outside of the class definition, you can simply use `child._Parent__lst` to access it where `child` is an instance of `Child`. Python **does not have access modifiers**.

Comment: @jasonharper In my course, I learned that private attributes are written with one underscore, its this wrong?

Comment: @Yaya123 By convention, a single underscore would be used to denote an attribute that is not part of the public API, yes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know private attributes are not a part of the public interface, I was asking if subclasses can still access these or not

Comment: @Yaya123 **did you try**? This seems like something you could have simply discovered yourself in a manner of seconds. As I stated, though, it is a *convention*. Python *doesn't have access modifiers* like, say, Java or C++

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I know I can do it, I'm asking if it should be done by convention. Similar to private attributes in public methods. I know you can access them, but your are not meant to.

Comment: Then you *really* must be clear when you are asking these questions. Fundamentally, this comes down to "whatever the documentation for the class says".

Comment: @Yaya123 *"Similar to private attributes in public methods"* -- Huh? What's wrong with a public method accessing a private attribute? For example, you could have a private attribute with a public getter but no setter. That setup is used all the time with `property`s.

Answer (score 3):

In python, *truly* private attributes / methods *don't exist*. There are only naming conventions. What this means is if an attribute / method has its name beginning with one underscore, it can still be accessed from anywhere, just like regular attributes / methods. The only thing that this does is serve as a reminder to yourself and let other developers know that this attribute was not meant to be accessed from the outside.

To answer your question, yes, you can use _lst in the function. Even in languages that do have real access modifiers, there is frequently a different keyword to distinguish attributes not accessible from anywhere vs those that are not accessible anywhere but derived classes. In python, this is generally signified with a double underscore (`__`) vs a single underscore (`_`). Double underscores are not meant to be accessed from anywhere, while single underscores can be accessed by derived classes. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-in-python-public-private-and-protected/) for more information.